# Error While creating the Network Load Balancing in Cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

Iam Trying to create Network Lode Balancing in Cloudformation But Stack it Getting fail with below error.

Error : Listener protocol 'TCP' must be one of 'HTTP, HTTPS' (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError;

```
  # Target Group
 LPTargetGroup:
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
Properties:
    HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
    HealthCheckProtocol: TCP
    HealthCheckPort: 450
    HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
    HealthyThresholdCount: 3
    Name: !Ref TargetName
    TargetType: instance
    Port: 450
    Protocol: TCP
    TargetGroupAttributes:
    - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
      Value: '20'
    Targets:
    - Id:
        Ref: WebEC2Instance1
      Port: 450
    - Id:
        Ref: WebEC2Instance2
      Port: 450
    - Id:
        Ref: WebEC2Instance3
      Port: 450                 
    UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
    VpcId:
      Ref: 'Vpc'
    Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: LPTargetGroup
    - Key: Port
      Value: 450

#ELB (NLB)
NLBListener:
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
Properties:
    DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref LPTargetGroup
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LPNetworkLoadBalancer
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: TCP
    Port: '443'
    Protocol: TCP
LPNetworkLoadBalancer:
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
Properties:
  Name: Lp-Web-NLB
  Scheme: internal
  Subnets:
   - !Select [ 0, !Ref Subnets ]
   - !Select [ 1, !Ref Subnets ]
   - !Select [ 2, !Ref Subnets ]
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS LoadBalancer to Listen on multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997188/aws-loadbalancer-to-listen-on-multiple-ports)

Answer (score 1):

Available protocols are determined by the Load Balancer type. The default type is Application Load Balancer, which supports HTTP and HTTPS protocols. If you want to use NLB you need to add `Type: network` to your template.

```
LPNetworkLoadBalancer:
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
Properties:
  Type: network
  Name: Lp-Web-NLB
  Scheme: internal
  Subnets:
   - !Select [ 0, !Ref Subnets ]
   - !Select [ 1, !Ref Subnets ]
   - !Select [ 2, !Ref Subnets ]
```